# Out-of-fashion pronominal adverbs

Tags: adverbs, adverb-position, writing-advice

I'm not a native English speaker. When writing papers, I find myself using English pronominal adverbs (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_pronominal_adverbs) rather often, especially 'therewith', 'therewithin', 'hereon', 'hereof', 'wherefore', etc.

At wikitionary these words are labeled as 'archaic'.
I am aware that these can be replaced by simpler variants like 'therein', but it feels as if the place and meaning of the sentence changes in an unintended way when simply replacing those words with their simpler counterparts.

What is the reason that those words are out of fashion?
And, how can I prevent the use of those?

Comment: For Dutch (Germanic language)-speaking people they indeed tend to come about more naturally :)

Comment: I've no explanation why once reasonably common words now often sound nigh-on unacceptable outside legalese. But if you want to sound natural in English, avoid them. An idiomatic rewrite often involves more words. Dictionaries point the way; as an individual example, involving 'therewith', compare the different renderings of Philippians 4:11 [[BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/philippians/4-11.htm)] in say the AV(KJV), and the NIV and NLT.

Comment: They can often be replaced by locutions such as "from this point", "in this way", "for that reason", "from here", etc. It's helpful if you give some specific examples, particularly when it comes to the question of whether alternatives change the meaning (although some of this might be considered off-topic if it's about the best way to phrase something, which is a matter of opinion and often doesn't have a factual answer).